# Expand recognisable input for confirm prompt in Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am currently working on a chatbot which uses confirm prompts throughout the conversation with my user.
It is being used for simple yes/no questions but most of these questions can also be answered with different sentences for example:

"Is this the correct product?"

1. Yes
2. Yes it is
3. That is the correct product

When I use a confirm prompt, the first two options work fine, but when someone says "That is the correct product", the confirm prompt does not recognize this as valid input. I've already looked into using [custom validators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465819/6351280), but that seemed to be useful if you wanted to verify recognized input, no so much a way to expand the recognized input itself.

Is there a way where I can expand the possible valid input for these prompts? For instance by using LUIS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening with your bot is that it's basically seeing the 'yes' portion of the first two responses at the same thing and ignoring the rest of the utterance of the second response. The reason it's not seeing your third response as the same is because it doesn't start with 'yes'. That being said, you have two options:

**OPTION 1**: Instead of using 'confirm prompt', you can use 'choice prompt'. ChoicePrompt has a 'synonym' property, which you can set when you build your choice prompt:

```
return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
    prompt: 'Please enter your mode of transport.',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices([
            {value:"my vehicle", synonyms:["car", "truck"]}, 
            {value:"public transporation", synonyms:["bus", "shuttle"]}, 
            {value: "slowly", synonyms:["walk", "bicycle"]}],
        )
    })
```

As you can see here, it allows a little bit of wiggle room for what a user might input.

[image: options]

[image: synonym example]

**OPTION 2**: The synonym route is where you want to go if you think your users are only going to put VERY LIMITED responses to the chatbot's prompts. If you want to expand your options for how a customer would react to this type of question, you are in fact going to need a language model of some sort. As you asked in your question, LUIS would be the choice to make.

You can build this by making a recognizer component which interacts with LUIS, it could look something like this.

```
export class LuisComponent {
private recognizer: LuisRecognizer;

  constructor(config: LuisApplication) {
    const luisConfig: LuisApplication = {applicationId: "LuisAppId", endpoint: "LuisAPIHostName" , endpointKey: "LuisAPIKey"} 
    this.recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisConfig, {}, true)
  };

  public async executeLuisQuery(context: TurnContext): Promise<RecognizerResult> {
    const result = await this.recognizer.recognize(context);
    return result;
  };
}
```

This will send your queries to LUIS and return the result of the query. The only thing you have to do is create a custom prompt which uses this component and returns the result from the prompt.

```
export class ConfirmPrompt extends Prompt<boolean> {

private luis: LuisComponent ;

constructor(id: string, recognizer: LuisComponent ) 
  super(id, validator);
  this.luis = recognizer;
};

protected async onRecognize(context: TurnContext, state: object, options: PromptOptions): Promise<PromptRecognizerResult<boolean>> {

  const luisResult = await this.luis.executeLuisQuery(context);
  const topIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult);

  let result: PromptRecognizerResult<boolean> = { succeeded: false, value: undefined };

  switch (topIntent) {

    case "Confirm": {
      result.succeeded = true;
      result.value = true;
      break;
    };

    case "No": {
      result.succeeded = true;
      result.value = false;
    };

    default: {
      result.succeeded = false;
    };
  };

  return result;
};

protected async onPrompt(context: TurnContext, state: object, options: 
  PromptOptions, isRetry: boolean): Promise<void> {

    if (isRetry && options.retryPrompt) {
      await context.sendActivity(options.retryPrompt, undefined, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
  } else if (options.prompt) {
      await context.sendActivity(options.prompt, undefined, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    };
  };
};
```

For something as simple as a confirm, you would just be adding the possible options for what people might say as a confirmation. You can see in my model below that I have 5 PAGES of possible utterances for what might be sent as a confirmation:

[image: testing confirm intent]

This particular intent only uses what I consider 'stock phrases', so I've basically added every option for how I think a user might confirm something.

Additionally (this is beyond the scope of your question, but good information) LUIS and other language understanding services also allow for the usage of what is called 'entities', so you can put a partial utterance, and mark the remainder as an entity, which allows for some variation of responses from users. The following is a screen shot of the 'book flight' intent, from the Bot Framework [Core Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) sample:

[image: Book Flight Intent from LUIS]

As you can see, this intent has label 'entities' "Airport" and "DateTime", so that further utterances of how a person might say 'Book me a flight to XYZ', without having to worry about putting in EVERY SINGLE POSSIBLE airport in the world in their model.

As you expand your chatbot, using a language understanding service like LUIS will allow you to have a more natural conversational flow with your customers/users. Good luck on your bot!

Comment: How did you explicitly add entities to the utterance? In my model it shows the entity name (e.g. Airport) but the model is using only the specific value (e.g. CLE) from the utterance. Would love to be able to leave those as generic entities.

Comment: You can double click the word in the utterance list on the LUIS portal. It will bracket, and a drop down saying 'Search for or create an entity' will pop up. You can do it there. If you chose 'simple entity', it will become an entity without any explicit values.

Comment: Here are my screenshots for doing this: https://imgur.com/a/4cMvThi

Comment: After reviewing I think what I'm looking for is Patterns, which I just now have figured out how to tag entities in those. I already have entities that are recognized in my utterances (mostly Regex entities), but I wanted a way to create an utterance with a non-specific value for the entity. That appears to be what Patterns does.

Comment: Hi JJ, thank you for your broad answer on the possible solutions for detecting user input. While it is a nice answer, I feel the 2nd part doesn't really explain how I could integrate LUIS together with confirm prompts in Bot Framework or replace the prompt for a LUIS code solution. Is this possible?

Comment: Very much so! It would be a matter of adding a LUIS component to your bot, and running all your responses through it. If it pings on a 'confirm' intent, then the response is routed through the confirm response. Give me an hour, and I'll stick some code in there to demonstrate.

Comment: I already figured it out and propose an edit with the code example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about these validators as I only write bots in C#, but my guess is they are more specific, like confirming that a number is a real number, for instance - I definitely think LUIS would be the way to go here.

Don't forget that you can grow the vocabulary over time very easily in the LUIS UI by reviewing what people are saying and making sure it's matching the correct intent. In fact, I'd suggest setting up telemetry in your app that, any time it can't identify something, you have it alert you so you can train it very quickly after a "failure".

To explain, let's say you include those 3 examples you gave above, but then in a week's time the user tries another example you never thought of - you would get an alert from your app, log in to the LUIS UI and deal with the new entry, and from then on it's part of the vocabulary,  without your needing to redeploy a completely new version of your app.

So, long story short, this is a better fit for LUIS, and it's exactly what it's designed for.